# Arduino Uno - External Power not working properly

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]I am a newbie to Arduino and created my first project. The project is using a Sharp short range sensor and a 7 seg LED board (http://embedded-lab.com/blog/new-version-of-max7219-based-4-digit-serial-seven-segment-led-display/) to count objects.

Everything works fine when on USB power to my computer or if I use a 5v 1A wall adapter with a USB cable. The problem is when I use an external power adapter or use a DC power supply to the Vin. The board powers up and I measured the output voltage on the 5v pin and is measuring around 4.8v.

The Sharp sensor is connected to the A0 Analog in and I see the voltage fluctuate when an object passes, but the LED is not displaying a value when on the external power. The display is connected to GRD, 5v where DIN, CLK, and LOAD pins of the display are connected to pins 7, 6, and 5 as the instructions stated.

I tried two different Arduino boards and several different AC to DC power adapters ranging from 9v to 12v plus used a DC power supply to the Vin and same results.

The code is below and pretty simple (although I am sure there is a lot better way of doing it but this is my first project in C so go easy on me and the function for digits is from a website and not written by me).

If a picture of the project would help I can upload one.

Any ideas or thoughts?
Thanks,
Steve

```
#include "LedControl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Arduino Pin 7 to DIN, 6 to Clk, 5 to LOAD, no.of devices is 1
LedControl lc = LedControl(7, 6, 5, 1);
int sensorpin = 0;      // analog pin used to connect the sharp sensor
int val = 0;            // variable to store the values from sensor(initially zero)
int cnt = 1;

void setup()
{
    // Initialize the MAX7219 device
    lc.shutdown(0, false);   // Enable display
    lc.setIntensity(0, 10);  // Set brightness level (0 is min, 15 is max)
    lc.clearDisplay(0);     // Clear display register


}
void loop()
{


    val = analogRead(sensorpin);       // reads the value of the sharp sensor
    if (val >= 650)
    {

    //write values to LED
    if (cnt<=9)
    {
        lc.setDigit(0, 0, cnt, false); // Display 4 to Digit 1-9, " "
    }
    if (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 99)
    {
        lc.setDigit(0, 0, getDigitFromNum(cnt,0), false); // Display 4 to Digit 1-9, " "
        lc.setDigit(0, 1, getDigitFromNum(cnt, 1), false); // Display 3 to Digit 1-9, " "
    }

    if (cnt >=100)
    {
        lc.setDigit(0, 0, getDigitFromNum(cnt, 0), false); // Display 4 to Digit 1-9, " "
        lc.setDigit(0, 1, getDigitFromNum(cnt, 1), false); // Display 3 to Digit 1-9, " "
        lc.setDigit(0, 2, getDigitFromNum(cnt, 2), false); // Display 2 to Digit 1-9, " "
    }

    delay(400);
    cnt++;

}
}

// Function: getDigitFromNum returns a digit at a given index of a integer.
// Goes from right to left with the starting index of 0.
int getDigitFromNum(int num, int digit) {
    num /= pow(10, digit);
    return num % 10;
}
// Function: getDigitFromDec returns a digit at a given index of a double.
// Goes from left to right with the starting index of 0.
int getDigitFromDec(double dec, int digit) {
    dec *= pow(10, digit);
    return (int)dec % 10;
}
// Function: getDigitFromNum returns the decimal values of a double.
double getDecimals(double dec) {
    return dec - (int)dec;
}
```

Comment: Maybe to much noise or load on the 5V regulator? How much power are you drawing? And what's wrong with just using a USB power supply? They are cheap and easy to find.

Comment: And a good clean picture, and schematic always helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Added a photo... not sure it shows it real well. Downloading  Fritzing now so schematic to follow. How do I measure how much power I am drawing (remember newb here). 

I want to ultimately use battery power. Any recommendations on a battery pack that will connect to the USB Type B port? Also I would like to understand what I am doing wrong or the issue.

Comment: Along with Passerby's comments, your stepping on your own brain. Do not over complicate the wheel. Stick with what works and make it more permanent. There is likely nothing wrong with your code or it would not work at all.

Comment: Do you have enough of current supply? What if your power supplies are just too low on current - cannot work properly because arduino cannot get enough current to power everything? Just try (if you have) something with 12V and 1A. It should be more than enough, but..at least, give it a try.

Comment: Passerby - Still working on the schematic - not sure how to represent the LED display board as it is not a standard part, but thanks for the tip on schematic vs drawing (once complete will upload). I looked into the USB banks and that looks reasonable and will research that, but still want to understand what is up with this. You mentioned noise. I have a few solder joints to connect the sensor and LED display back to the 5v. Could that cause an issue for the regulator? I read where the external jack is connected to a voltage regulator but the USB is not.

Comment: Sparky256 - thanks and yeah I have stepped all over my brain on this one. Although new to Arduino and C programming, background is in software and years ago played with electronics (long before Arduino). I didn't see the code as an issue, but a lot of people I notice ask for it. Also with trying multiple boards and power supplies ruled them out. Has me puzzled on this even though I am new to this.

Comment: Jakey - One the external wall jack power supplies I tried is a 12v 1A supply. The other one is a 9v 1a supply that came with a kit. I also used a Dr. Meter DC power supply connected to the Vin pin. It only allows the board to draw the max current it can handle. I pushed the voltage up to 12v and the board would only draw around .800 mAh. The power supply of course can push a lot more than that. Both of these produced the same result.

Comment: Okay. What if (I know this is not recommended, but) you connect +5V to a 5V pin on arduino? Just give it a try.
On the other hand: Why don't you (in this case) just power your Arduino with phone USB charger? Just plug in usb A -> usb B cable and you're ready to go.

Comment: I might not be able to respond as much for the next week because of travel for work. I am thinking it is something with the LED board. I am going to contact the supplier on that and see what they think. Thanks everyone and will update as soon as I can.

Comment: Jakey - right now I am powering the device using a USB phone charger and working good. Two things, I want the device to be portable so running off batteries is preferred and secondly would like to understand why it is not working. Is there something special or different you have to do when uploading the code to the device to have it run off of external power?

Not sure what you mean by connecting a +5v to the 5v pin. I thought the one 5v pin was a voltage out?

Comment: 5V pin is voltage out. But if you connect the 5V power supply to this pin, arduino should turn on. It's not good for 7805, but if you try it for 3 seconds, won't do any harm.
About external voltage: Give it a try of a battery (or socket charger) to a DC connector left of the USB connector (watch the polarity!).
Report results afterwards. It shouldn't be much different, but in this case, we'll just give a kick in the dark.
PS: Just measure the battery/power supply(NOT USB!) voltage for sure. Just to make sure, it gives out as much as supposed to (or at least 7V, but preferable more than 9V).

Comment: @Jakey `It's not good for 7805, but if you try it for 3 seconds, won't do any harm.` You're talking nonsense. First there is no "7805", and second the LDO that is there doesn't give the slightest damn. Power has no concept of "in" or "out" - it only exists. The only possible danger is if you power through 5V and try to draw current from VIN to power things - then it can flow backwards through the regulator. Other than that, powering into 5V is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between powering from USB and powering through the barrel jack is the voltage is reduced to 5V through a Low Dropout (LDO) voltage regulator. These are typically a clone of the popular LM1113-50 and vary in current handling capacity from around 500mA up to 1A.

I notice your board is not a genuine Arduino - therefore the components used may be at the cheaper end. So we'll assume a low-grade LDO that only handles 500mA before going into thermal shutdown with good heatsinking. Since there isn't on these boards we shall therefore assume a maximum of 400mA before it gets too hot. Probably somewhat conservative.

So if your entire circuit is drawing more than about 400mA you can expect the regulator to shut down, or at least to reduce the current and/or voltage available.

The fact you're seeing 4.8V rather than 5V could be an indication that there is *voltage droop* occurring - i.e., the regulator is not able to supply enough current so the voltage drops. This would be accompanied by the regulator getting very hot.

The regulator is the device with 3 pins on the right side and a single tab on the left directly above the barrel jack socket. See how hot that is getting.

As a rule of thumb if you can hold your finger on it without crying for 10 seconds it's not too hot.

---

Another thing you can do is to reduce your circuit to the bare minimum. Unplug absolutely everything and upload the Blink example sketch. Power that from the external DC and see if the LED blinks for you. If it does then the power supply is working OK. You can then add your peripherals one at a time to see when it fails.

If it doesn't blink then there must be something inherently wrong with the supply.

One possibility is that the LDO is *oscillating* due to insufficient or incorrect input and output capacitors. This basically means the "5V" voltage it gives out is actually wildly swinging between say 4.5V and 5V or 4.75V and 5.25V, which really confuses the microcontroller. Cheap LDOs are often more sensitive to the capacitors they are paired with and can suffer from this kind of problem.

To diagnose that kind of thing you would really need access to an oscilloscope to analyse the voltage.

If it is oscillating a 10µF ceramic capacitor connected between the lower two pins of the LDO (as orientated in your picture - that is Vout and GND) may cure it. A 1206 surface mount capacitor fits nicely across those pins and is reasonably easy to hand solder. You could also try a through-hole capacitor (ceramic again) between 5V and GND on the power header, but you really want it as close to the LDO as you can get it, so soldered direct to the LDO's pins is best.